# PHP random INT with evenly distributed order of magnitude results

Tags: php

PHP `rand(min, max)` between 1 and 9999 gives almost all results with 4 digits (because there are ~90% of the numbers with 4 digits). So, if I ran it 1000 times, roughly ~90% of them will probably have 4 digits.

Is there a way to generate a random INT from 1 to 9999 and that the output number have the same chance of having 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits without doing it manually?

By doing it manually I mean like this:

```
$digits = rand(1, 4);
$num = '';

for($i = 0; $i < $digits; $i++){
    $num .= rand(0, 9);
}

$final = intval($num);
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that what you are planning to do will bias the results towards lower numbers. For example, there are ~9000 4 digit numbers, 900 3-digit, ~90 2 digit and 10 1-digit numbers between 0 and 9999. What you are proposing will make 0 to 9 show up 25% of the time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, if I ran it 1000 times, roughly ~90% of them will probably have 4 digits.

That's exactly how uniform distributions work. There's no out of the box function to do what you're after, so you have to make some statistics magic.

What I'm thinking of is: generate a random number between 0 and 1. If it's between 0 and .25, generate another random number between 0 and 9. If it's between .25 and .5, generate another random number between 10 and 99, and so on and so forth. Then, you'd have 1/4 chance of getting each order of magnitude.

This will obviously have a bias towards the lower numbers though, since there are less of them. For example, 1 has a `25% / 10 = 2.5%` chance, while 1001 has a `25% / 8998 = 0.00277%` chance.

It'd go something like this:

```
<?php
$initial = rand(0, 100)/100;
if ($initial < .25) {
    $random = rand(0, 9);
}
elseif ($initial < .5) {
    $random = rand(10, 99);
}
elseif ($initial < .75) {
    $random = rand(100, 999);
}
elseif ($initial >= .75) {
    $random = rand(1000, 9999);
}
var_dump($random);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/opRPV)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this will have a bias towards the lower numbers? If $initial is random then after 1000 iterations, $initial will be ~250 times 0-.25, ~250 times .25-5, ~250 times .5-.75 and ~250 times .75-1 right?

Comment: do you make a bicycle?

Comment: Oh I get it now, yeah this is the intended functionality, thanks!

Comment: @soft87 what? haha I don't get it